# If electric field is conservative then line integral along closed path is zero, then why is potential not zero?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics

Here in the first image it is said $\displaystyle \int_a ^b E\cdot \mathrm dl\,$ is $0 $:

[image]

Here in the second image it looks like $\displaystyle \int_a ^b E\cdot \mathrm dl\,$ is not $0$:

[image]

If field is conservative which it is here, then closed line integral is 0 which is the case in the first image, but the potential is also a line integral so why is it not 0

Please help me understand this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The integral around any *closed* path is zero.  But $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ are not the same point: the path is not closed, so the integral does not have to be zero.

Comment: But a and b are different points in the first image, they say (DJ Griffiths) 'a' is $R_a$ from the charge at origin and b is $R_b$ from the origin, then how can a and b be equal ? So how can the line integral be 0 there ?

Comment: Yes, and then he gets an expression for that integral in general in terms of $r_a$ and $r_b$ and shows that it is zero *if $\vec{a}$ & $\vec{b}$ are the same point*: it's not *always* zero.

Comment: It will be 0 if a and b are at the same point for any field wouldn't it ? because it's just subtracting same values to get 0 ?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/ruc0gV4

In the figure a and b can be different points and $R_a$ and $R_b$ can be equal too ?

Where is the closed path here ? All i see is a curvy line from a to b.

Comment: Yes, they can be different points: different points can have the same potential.  However identical points *must* have the same potential.  This is part of the proof that there is in fact a well-defined potential.

Comment: I think I get it now

Comment: So what happens when a and b are not the same point ...so curl of E is 0 only for equipotential points ?

Comment: *"The integral around any closed path is zero."* - [Green's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem):